# Grand total for an SSRS calculated field

Tags: reporting-services

i have a column in the report in which it stores calculated values depending on a set of iif statements, and calculate subtotals:

```
=sum(iif(Fields!EDLCode.Value = "X", Fields!Amount.Value, 0)/3 + iif(Fields!EDLCode.Value = XXX, Fields!SubjectAmt.Value, 0) - iif(InStr(Fields!Description1.Value, "YYY"),Fields!SubjectAmt.Value,0))
```

Question is how to show a grand total for that column in the report? Now it looks like that:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I had to set CDec(0) instead of just 0.

```
=sum(
iif(Fields!EDLCode.Value = "X", Fields!Amount.Value, CDec(0))/3 + 
iif(Fields!EDLCode.Value = XXX, Fields!SubjectAmt.Value, CDec(0)) - 
iif(InStr(Fields!Description1.Value, "YYY"),Fields!SubjectAmt.Value,CDec(0)))
```

This is working now.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your expression

1. No quotes around `XXX`
2. `InStr` returns a value but you do not do anything with it

I have assume for the `InStr` function you are checking if `"YYY"` appears in the string, if not then modify the comparison to suit your needs..

Try this

```
=SUM(
    IIF(Fields!EDLCode.Value = "X", Fields!Amount.Value, 0)/3 + 
    IIF(Fields!EDLCode.Value = "XXX", Fields!SubjectAmt.Value, 0) - 
    IIF(InStr(Fields!Description1.Value, "YYY") >0, Fields!SubjectAmt.Value, 0)
    )
```

Comment: Sorry, XXX is a number actually. I just replaced it with placeholder. Anyway, this is a code that returns that subtotal numbers - 98892.45 and 77882.57 (details are concealed). But when i try to use it to count totals - it throws an error, still. Changes didn't help either.

Comment: Can you edit your question and post some sample data with expected outcome. Show the exact expression used, if you need to swap out values in your sample, make sure they are of the same datatype. Also, what error do you get? Finally, show the datatypes of all fields/columns that are referenced.

Comment: well, basically - the report is retrieving income data for a single person, and sort income by grouping it by specific earn codes. Subtotals for each code is calculated, using the formula above (there's multiple lines for each, hidden, only subtotals shown). As can be seen in the screenshot above - subtotals are calculated properly, but grand total, which should sum subtotals and ideally return 0 - throws an error. All elements should be numeric (12,2). Somehow the problem is only with grand total. Subtotals calculated just right.

Comment: And a strange part - when i remove 2 any IIF from that statement - error is still there. Something seems to be wrong...

Comment: read my last comment, supply what I have asked for an I will try to help. If you can't do this, I can't help you